# Truetext & falsetext not displaying while using toggling button in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

When I use toggle button its not showing the True text and False text while I toggle it. ShowLabel is set to true & the display mode is `DisplayMode.Edit`.

How to make the falsetext and truetext Visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a weird behavior (bug) on focus of [toggle control](https://youtu.be/qpcU1JV7pOY), that too only happening in chrome browser. [Read more](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Toggle-text-disappears-on-focus/td-p/213405/page/2)

Workaround from community:

> Only workaround I know of is to remove the text in the toggle,  reduce the width of the toggle, and add your own label with an if statement pointing at the the toggle status.